# Running Ant script in IntelliJ results in script opening in editor

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

I've got a custom ant script for building and other fun stuff.  IntelliJ has very nice integration for handling Ant tasks.  However, every time I run a task IntelliJ opens the script in my editor panel.  It moves to the line of the task I'm running and then I close it; actually I now have it in its own panel, minimized to the max.

Is there anyway to disable this behavior? I just want the Ant script to run the task, pop up its own panel with some feedback (which it does) and then allow me to keep coding without having to close the script.  Please tell me this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man, I can't believe this only had 4 views, and two of those were me.  Pretty weak.

Anyways, I've got a solution that might help someone else down the road.  In the *Messages* window that pops up when the ant build starts there is an *Auto Scroll to Source* button.  Make sure this button is unchecked.